# MongoDB First Column+Second Column>2

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to develop myself about mongodb. and asking some question for two days.

yesterday, I've learned that "First column > Second Column". In mongodb I've made this like:

```
$hg = $coll_mac->aggregate(array(
                array('$match'=>array('sezon_kodu'=>$sezon, 'tarih'=>array('$lt'=>$time))),
                array('$project'=>
                    array(
                        'c'=>array('$cmp'=>array('$ft1','$ft2'))
                    )
                ),
                array('$match'=>array('c'=>array('$gt'=>0))),
                array( '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '',
                    'total' => array('$sum' => '$c')
                        ))
            ));
```

Now, how can I write this?
"Select records that (First column + Second Column)>2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said last night, you ca use `$add`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/add/

```
$hg = $coll_mac->aggregate(array(
    array('$match'=>array('sezon_kodu'=>$sezon, 'tarih'=>array('$lt'=>$time))),
    array('$project'=>
        array(
            'c'=>array('$add'=>array('$ft1','$ft2'))
        )
    ),
    array('$match'=>array('c'=>array('$gt'=>2))),
));
```

Comment: @Derick Hmm well the one liner in the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/add/ isn't the easiest thing to understand